# Is Bhutan an extremely happy country?

Tags: psychology, sociology, bhutan

[Supposedly](https://www.oneworldeducation.org/bhutan-worlds-happiest-country) Bhutan consistently ranks as one of the happiest countries in the world. Bhutan seems to have a reputation as a eco-friendly liberal paradise, and pages [like this](http://www.lifehack.org/articles/communication/8-things-bhutan-people-differently-that-make-them-the-happiest-people.html) claim that their environmental and spiritual outlook makes them less materialistic and happier than most countries. The Bhutanese government even promotes the idea of Gross National Happiness (GNH) as being, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_National_Happiness), "a commitment to building an economy that would serve Bhutan's culture based on Buddhist spiritual values, instead of western material development gauged by gross domestic product (GDP)."

Is there a factual basis for these claims? I'm personally extremely skeptical since these claims seem to be serving the vested interests of the Bhutanese government while appealing to western new-age spiritual trends. I'm also aware that there are methodological issues with measuring happiness on a quantitative scale. Is there concrete evidence for or against their claims?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No.

Bhutan ranks 84 out of 157 in the [World Happiness Report](http://worldhappiness.report/) ((Download [PDF for 2016 version](http://worldhappiness.report/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2016/03/HR-V1_web.pdf)), published by the [United Nations Sustainable Development Solutions Network](http://unsdsn.org/). This is based on 2013-2015 rankings for a Gallup poll using a Cantril ladder (self-ranking on a scale from 0-10). (The typical annual sample was 1,000 people per country).

There is also a [Happy Planet Index](http://happyplanetindex.org/) compiled by the [Global Footprint Network](http://www.footprintnetwork.org/public). Their [2016 dataset](http://happyplanetindex.org/s/hpi-data-2016.xlsx) (Excel sheet) ranks Bhutan 56 out of 140, but that uses the same UN data together with 3 other factors: Life expectancy, Ecological footprint, and Inequality of outcomes.

Note 1: Bhutan ranked 79 in [2015](http://worldhappiness.report/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2015/04/WHR15.pdf)

Note 2: Here is statistician Nic Marks's [TED talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/nic_marks_the_happy_planet_index?language=en) about the Happy Planet Index.